# jQuery json call not working on mls/idx page

Tags: jquery, cross-domain, jsonp

My real estate site incorporates mls/idx data from third party server. The jQuery function is working perfectly on my own site, but whenever on the mls/idx page, the jQuery call is not working. On the idx page, here is how jQuery library is included:

```
....    
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var jq = $.noConflict();
</script>

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.0.0/prototype.js'></script></head>
....
```

And here is how the  element is defined and jQuery called:

```
<select id="select_agent_id" name="select_agent_id">
    <option value="cw123">C.W.</option>
    <option value="ds123" selected="selected">D.S.</option>
    <option value="jl456">J.L.</option>
</select>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
jq(document).ready(function() {
    jq("#select_agent_id").change(function() {
        jq.getJSON("http://mysite.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/get_agent_info.php", {"agent_id" : jq(this).val()}, function(agent,status) {
            jq("#first_name").html(agent.first_name);
            jq("#last_name").html(agent.last_name);
            jq("#agent_title").html(agent.agent_title);
            ....
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Can someone please help me find what's wrong? The 3rd party idx provider not helping at all. Thanks a lot!

Comment: what if you change to: src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" - put the specific version you need in for the `1.9.1` and no http in front. RE: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide?hl=ja#jquery

Comment: And is the jQuery library at the top of your scripts? Any errors in the console?

Answer (score 1):

Just include

> callback=?

as a parameter in your URL. That will convert the call to JSONP which is necessary to make cross-domain calls.

More info: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: Thank you KingKongFrog, it's indeed considered cross-domain request, so jsonp is needed.